# Wamp is not completely starting

Tags: php, apache, sockets, service, wamp

Currently i am using Wamp 2.5 version.

This is what the setup i have installed: **wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-64b.exe**

The wamp is set to orange, checked with port: 80. Earlier it was used by SQL services. Stopped all SQL, now its been used by:

[image]

But still i am not able to get wamp to change green.

I have enough googled, but still could not solve this. Anybody had this issue earlier and resolved?

I have Visual C++ 2012 framework of 64bit and 32bit installed into my system.

FYI: System is running in LAN

Following is the error i get when i debug:

[image]

Comment: change the port 80 to 81 in apache config file. Then, use localhost:81/project

Comment: Tried that as well but its of no use:

Listen 0.0.0.0:81
Listen [::0]:81
ServerName localhost:81

And also tried with my IP address as well configuring. Following is the error reference 

![Error](http://imgur.com/lKioGfd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the wampmanager icon is Orange, and when you check port 80 it says that Apache is using it (which it does as per the info on your question) **then it is the MySQL service that has not started**.

If you have previously tried installing Apache/MySQL/PHP manually i.e. not WAMPServer or XAMPP then there is probably a rouge my.ini or my.cnf file on your system.

Do a search for `my.ini` and `my.cnf` across your whole C: drive. If there is a rouge `my.ini` it is probably in `C:\windows` but check the whole of C: just to be safe. If you find one of these files anywhere other than in the `\wamp\bin\mysql\mysqlx.y.z` folder structure delete it.

There is a search order that mysql uses to find a my.ini and it is

```
%WINDIR%\my.ini, %WINDIR%\my.cnf    
C:\my.ini, C:\my.cnf
INSTALLDIR\my.ini, INSTALLDIR\my.cnf
```

**Additional Info**

Also look in the registry, if you had used a mysql .msi install at some time you may have entries in the Registry like this

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MySQL AB
```

Or if using 64bit Windows

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MYSQL AB
```

WampServers install does not use these so they are unnecessary and this coudl also be confusing MySQL as to where it gets its ini file from.

Also have a look at the Windows Event log using `Windows Event Viewer` if MySQL fails to start before it can write to its own log file, it will write errors into the Event log.

**Additional Info 2**

I just looked at the image you linked to.

You have another MySQL installed. Theres no point having 2 MySQL Servers installed, and they will always get in each others way unless you really know what you are doing.

If you are not using the other version of MySQL Server, uninstall it.

Alternatively, using the services snapin `services.msc` at least disable the other MySQL.
I would bet that that service has already grabbed port 3306 (the MySQL default port) so thats why the MYSQL in WAMPServer is not starting.

WAMPServers MySQL Service is called `wampmysqld` or `wampmysqld64`

The default used by your other installed MySQL is probably just `MYSQLD`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RiggsFolly. I found my.ini and other .ini files related to MySQL on search [Searched INI's](http://imgur.com/edDdnmY). So i deleted everything as u suggested and restarted also but still unable to start the wamp. FYI: Earlier it was installed in C drive, now its in D drive. I deleted all the references in C now and i did not find anything out of bin directory in D drive. Its strange for me. Thinking of to install the earlier version of wamp now... :(

Comment: You have 2 MySQL Servers installed. See `Additional Info 2` and get rid of it.

Comment: Yup, you are right. I have installed Mysql Work bench as well as Wamp. That would be resulting to this conflict. Whereas Wamp 2.4 Version will not give such strange problems. Just changing of ports has solved my issue. Ill follow your steps and if successful ill accept your answer. And one more frustrating thing, people here just come to down vote. Why they are so? that to check with the reputation of seeker and just down vote to cancel our account access. How to catch and report them?

Comment: I see, that explains it. There are 2 versions of MySQL Workbench, one comes with a MySQL Server and one comes with just the Workbench. You could try uninstalling the `Workbench with MySQL` and then just install the plain Workbench. BACKUP ANY DATABASES FIRST!! That is the only reason you had a problem, so there is no reason why you cannot install the latest WAMPServer 2.5 once you get rid of the other MySQL Server.

Comment: PS. Stick to a 32 bit WAMPServer, theres not point in the 64 bit unless you are a real GEEK. Lots of PHP extension you may want to use are still not coverted to 64bit and probably wont be until PHP itself gets a complete 64bit port, current it is just **Experimental**

Answer (score -1):

This can be a issue sometimes due to an installation of TeamViewer or Skype on the same machine.

You can Change the Port of Apache by Opening Notepad with Admin Rights. Open File

```
path to wamp\bin\apache\Apache\conf\httpd.conf
```

Change

```
Listen 80
```

to say

```
Listen 81 or Listen 8080
```

And now the Wamp can be accessed from

```
localhost:81 or localhost:8080
```

Comment: these are all basic stuff which i tried before posting. Was unsuccessful. Please suggest me some better option...

Comment: His Apache has started and is using port 80! See the question. Skype and TeamViewer can use port 80, but his question shows port 80 being used by Apache.

Comment: I am tired up solving this as i dint find any good search results or answers. I ended up with earlier version using wamp 2.2. People just down vote my question without any sense here. Not even ready to answer. They will get to know once they face this problem. I really regret with the votings happen in Stackoverflow.